# ICollection<T>.Contains on custom types

Tags: c#, .net, collections, contains

If I have a (reference - does it matter?) type *MyType* which does not override the *Equals* method, what heuristics will be used when determining if an *ICollection<MyType>* contains a given instance of the type?

What's the best way to use my own heuristics (e.g. check for the equality of the *Id* property value)?

Comment: What specific collection are you using?

Comment: System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because your type doesn't override Equals, the default implementation of Equals will be used, i.e. reference equality.  So Contains will be true if the collection contains *that very instance*.

To use your own comparison, implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` (e.g. to compare the Ids) and pass an instance of your comparer into the Contains method.  (This assumes you are able to use LINQ extensions, as the "native" `ICollection<T>.Contains` method doesn't have the IEqualityComparer overload.)

Comment: out of interest are value types treated equally, and why not simply override the equals method?

Comment: Value types are considered equal if all of their fields are equal.  Of course, you can override Equals on a value type just as on a reference type, and can write a custom IEqualityComparer for a value type just as for a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not defined by `ICollection<T>`- different implementations can use different methods. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56.aspx):

> Implementations can vary in how they
>   determine equality of objects; for
>   example, `List<T>` uses
>   `Comparer<T>.Default`,
>   whereas `Dictionary<TKey,
>   TValue>` allows the user to specify
>   the `IComparer<T>`
>   implementation to use for comparing
>   keys

In most cases it will just compare the references, but you should check the documentation for the specific  `ICollection<T>` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the reference (address in memory) will be compared...

If the reference is not good enough for you then you might compare the ID, as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN:

> Implementations can vary in how they
>   determine equality of objects; for
>   example, List<(Of <(T>)>) uses
>   Comparer<(Of <(T>)>)..::.Default,
>   whereas Dictionary<(Of <(TKey,
>   TValue>)>) allows the user to specify
>   the IComparer<(Of <(T>)>)
>   implementation to use for comparing
>   keys.

The best way to do it on your own is to use the overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{
    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```