# List.Contains doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list which contains objects but these objests aren't unique in the list. I wrte this code to make unique them in another list:

```
 foreach (CategoryProductsResult categoryProductsResult in categoryProductsResults.Where(categoryProductsResult => !resultSet.Contains(categoryProductsResult)))
 {
    resultSet.Add(categoryProductsResult);
 }
```

But at the end resultSet is the same with categoryProductsResults.

categoryProductsResult's second row :

[image]

resultSet first row:

[image]

As you can see resultSet's first row and categoryProductsResult's second row is the same but it adds the second row to resultSet.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Show us where you override `.equals()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Contains` uses the default comparer which is comparing references since your class does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

```
class CategoryProductsResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...

    public override bool  Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null)return false;
        CategoryProductsResult other = obj as CategoryProductsResult;
        if(other == null)return false;
        return other.Name == this.Name;
    }

    public override int  GetHashCode()
    {
         return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use:

```
resultSet = categoryProductsResults.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

List uses the comparer returned by EqualityComparer.Default and according to the documentation for that:

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the
>   System.IEquatable(Of T) interface and, if so, returns an
>   EqualityComparer(Of T) that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it
>   returns an EqualityComparer(Of T) that uses the overrides of
>   Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

So you can either implement IEquatable on your custom class, or override the Equals (and GetHashCode) methods to do the comparison by the properties you require. Alternatively you could use linq:

bool contains = list.Any(i => i.Id == obj.Id);

Answer (score 1):

Each `categoryProductsResult` is different to each other. It's like something your can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). If you want a simpler one and the ProductId is your unique identifier. Just do the code below:

```
foreach (CategoryProductsResult categoryProductsResult in categoryProductsResults.Where(categoryProductsResult => resultSet.ProductId !=categoryProductsResult.ProductId)
{
    resultSet.Add(categoryProductsResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference objects in a list are indexed by their hash code.  So, `Contains` will never find a reference object with the same hash code (unless you override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementation in the class.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143815/icollectiont-contains-on-custom-types) explains.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your current item is contained in your target list for each iteration. Currently you check once at the start of the loop, which means none of your items is in the target list.

I think [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb348436.aspx) is already doing what you want, you might want to use this extension instead of your own loop.