# c# Check if custom class is in list<t>

Tags: c#

I have a list of custom class called `List<Notifications>`.

The class is below:

```
public class Notification
{
    public enum Type {

        Promotion,
       Other
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public Type NotificationType { get; set; }

}
```

Before adding an instance of the Notification class to my custom list, I want to check if it is already in the list.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ICollection<T>.Contains on custom types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143815/icollectiont-contains-on-custom-types)

Comment: What counts as "already exists"? Is the ID enough?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, I want to check if the ID of the class is in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 1.) [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but then you have to override `Equals` (+ `GethashCode`).

```
bool contains = list.Contains(someNotificationInstance);
```

For example:

```
public class Notification
{
    public enum Type {

        Promotion,
       Other
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public Type NotificationType { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Notification && string.Equals(ID, ((Notification)obj).ID);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID == null ? 0 : ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

2.) another option is to provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Notification>` for `Contains`:

```
public class NotificationComparer : IEqualityComparer<Notification>
{
    public bool Equals(Notification x, Notification y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Notification obj)
    {
        return obj.ID == null ? 0 : obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

On this way you don't need to modify the original class. You can use it in this way:

```
bool contains = list.Contains(someInstance, new NotificationComparer());
```

3.) Probably the easiest approach is using `Enumerable.Any`:

```
bool contains = list.Any(n => someInstance.ID == n.ID);
```

4.) The most efficient approach is using a set if no duplicates are allowed in the collection anyway. Then you can use the first or second approaches for a [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var set = new HashSet<Notification>(new NotificationComparer());
set.Add(instance1);
bool contains = !set.Add(instance2);
```

Comment: Or just select the IDs, as per Marko's solution. Which is the most appropriate depends on how often this precise notion of equality is useful, I guess. (I'd also implement `IEquatable<Notification>` and seal the class, mind you).

Comment: @JonSkeet: maybe i should have used a different order but i have provided multiple ways. The `IEquatable` is another, but that should do.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with `Contains` method.

```
if (!mylist.Select(l => l.ID).Contains(mynewid)) {
   var item = new Notifcation();
   item.ID = mynewid;
   item..... // fill the rest

   mylist.Add(item);
}
```

Maybe a better approch would be use of [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).